# Background-image cut by degress, is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I got 2 div's with background-images, i only want the images displayed like in my Awesome drawing, is this possible?

[image: What i want]

Comment: You would need to use a canvas for that sort of image - this was my attempt a while back: https://jsfiddle.net/03zvv1sx/.  Or you could try something with a [clipping mask](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) but I don't think that is compatible with all browsers yet (unless you used an svg)

Comment: Post the code you have and I'll might have a solution for that